# What should be the binding for mouse click?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=minimapButton}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
</DataTrigger>
```

The binding above is using `IsMouseOver` which refer to the element name `minimapButton`. 
What should be the code for mouse click? `IsMouseClicked`? `IsMouseLeftDown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a new event for the button click.

```
    <Button Click="button1_Click" />
```

And the code behind

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=minimapButton}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
</DataTrigger>   , i have to do the datatrigger binding with something like ismouseclicked but not ismouseover

Comment: What element does the DataTrigger belong to? You need to add the click event to it.

Comment: It is a popup element. so there are no way to modify the current code from IsMouseOver to something like IsMouseClicked?

Comment: Only by using IsMouseCaptured, but that will only last while the mouse is down.

Answer (score 1):

I would try **IsMouseCaptured**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.contentelement.ismousecaptured.aspx

Comment: it only return true while mouse is down. However, i want it to return true always whenever the button is clicked

Comment: You need to register a `Click` event.

Comment: @Tomislav Markovski, how should i do tat in xaml?

Comment: @DEN Do you have to use binding? I think a click event or MouseLeftButtonDown would be fine. DataTriggers are more for actual values of the binding you are evaluating. I don't think using it in the context of an event is overly intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in MVVm you cay try the Command or the expression interaction to catch the mouse click to the view model.